# List box - On Change formula

Tags: formula, powerapps

I have a list box (called «Month») in my form called Dashboard.
However, I’m struggling to automatically update the values(Gallery) in the form when I change the month in the list box.

As of now, I need to click on the “Filtergallery” before the values change.
Does anyone have an “On change - update all” formula that would solve this?

Best regards
Ola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerApps does not normally need actions to update items.
You should set the Items property of your gallery to something like

```
Filter(MyTable, MyMonthColumn=Month.Selected.Value)
```

The items displayed in the gallery should change automatically when the selected month is changed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help !